# Was bedeutet »Rohrbast«?

Tags: meaning

Im [Wikipedia-Artikel über Strandkorb](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strandkorb#Beschreibung) habe ich das Wort *Rohrbast* gefunden:

> 95 Prozent der Strandkörbe sind aus Kunststoffstreifen geflochten; wurde Naturmaterial verwendet, ist dies in der Regel aus Asien importiertes lackiertes **Rohrbast** aus Bambus oder Rattan.

Ich verstehe, dass das Rohrbast eine Wortzusammensetzung aus *Rohr* und *Bast* ist.

Das Wort habe ich nicht auf [Duden.de](https://duden.de) gefunden.
So wie ich es verstehe, hat es mit der Korbflechterei zu tun und gemäß [Peddig-Keel](https://www.peddig-keel.ch/produkte/flechtmaterial/stuhlflechtrohr-div-flechtmaterial/rohrbast) ist es fast äquivalent zum Flechtrohr. Ist diese Beschreibung korrekt? Gibt es eine bessere?

Comment: Ggf. bei "Flechtwerk Wilhelm Walterscheid" nachfragen: http://www.sonnenschein-steinfurt.de/flechtwerk-wilhelm-walterscheid/

Comment: Rohrbast ist ein Material zur Herstellung kommerzieller Produkte - und zum Basteln, was aber nur zufällig mit "Bast" beginnt ;-) Insofern halte ich die Website eines Verkäufers durchaus für korrekt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bast sind Pflanzenfasern, die unter der Rinde liegen und sehr langgestreckte, stabile Zellen haben, so dass sie bestens geeignet sind zum Binden und Pflechten.

Nimmt man nun (beispielsweise für die Herstellung von Strandkörben) getrocknete, hohle, röhrenförmige Halme (z.B. aus Schilf oder künstlich nachempfundenes Schilf), nennt man das Rohrbast.

Answer (score -3):

*Bast* sounds to me like a natural textile thing.
*Rohr* is a tube, or rather a cane.
So it’s that grassy stuff that you use to make baskets.

Wiktionary has [a good etymology for "bast"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bast#:%7E:text=From%20Middle%20English%20bast%2C%20from,basc%20(%E2%80%9Cnecklace%E2%80%9D)%2C):

> From Middle English bast, from Old English bæst (“bast, inner bark of trees from which ropes were made”), from Proto-Germanic *bastaz (“bast, rope”) (compare the Swedish bast, Dutch bast, German Bast), perhaps an alteration of Proto-Indo-European *bʰask-, *bʰasḱ- (“bundle”) (compare Middle Irish basc (“necklace”), Latin fascis (“bundle”), Albanian bashkë (“tied, linked”)).

This is a Latin *fascis:*

[image]

People often say that it’s a bundle of sticks, but I would say it’s more like reed *(Riet* in German). Hollow, quite flexible tubes that are actually hard to break; they bend but do not break. And if you bundle them, they don’t even bend any more, that makes the image of *fascis* for fascism even more powerful for a collectivist statist ideology. Digressing a little, but it’s to illuminate the full spectrum of why I intuitively thought of Bast as a textile rather than a stick.

And *Rohr* is just emphasizing that its a reed, or in German a *Halm;* think of *Strohalm* for drinking straw.

Comment: Da die Frage auf Deutsch ist, würde ich dich bitten, deine Antwort um eine Deutsche zu ergänzen, [siehe dazu auch hier](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1049/30455).  Wenn du nicht sicher bist, was die Frage vom OP ist, nutze die Kommentarfunktion, ehe du eine Antwort postest, die vielleicht völlig an der Frage vorbei geht. Davon abgesehen, ist dein PS ziemlich unhöflich (-1).

Comment: I removed most of the comments as well as off-topic asides in the answer. Please [be nice](/conduct) and [edit] your question so that it reflects your current best answer and not its history (which is [available](https://german.stackexchange.com/posts/61106/revisions) to everybody who cares anyway).